# (Azure APGW / SSL certificate) Intermediate certificate is missing in Azure Application Gateway. Wrong certificate?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, azure-application-gateway

I have a Drupal web app hosted on a VM in Azure. We want to set up an end to end SSL connection between the Application Gateway and the web app. For some specific reasons, we have to use a company self-signed certificate. This certificate is already uploaded in the keyvault by my client. Lets say the certificate is for `foo-test.bar.com`. So after setting up everything including listener, backend sets and the backend itself on the VM, I got a status  `Unhealthy` an error in the APGW while checking the backend's health

```
The Intermediate certificate is missing from the backend server chain. Please ensure that the certificate chain is complete and correctly ordered on the backend server.
```

So I guess that there was a certificate problem in the backend but I don't have a clear idea how to resolve it. Here what I've done so far

- Extract the certificate in .PFX format and install it on the backend
- Use the same certificate above in the listener configuration by referencing the keyvault
- Upload the root CA certificate and select `No` at `Backend server’s certificate is issued by a well-known CA` (done by someone else)

Other problem I discovered while checking the certificate `foo-test.bar.com` in the `.cer` format is the root certificate is missing in the certification path. I can see the message `The issuer of this certificate could not be found` in the certificate status. However if I click on the top most level, I can see who is the root CA in the Issued by field. You can see it in the photo below

[image: certification path]
[image: Missing root CA]

So I had suspicion about the integrity of the certificate. I had a call with my client about this issue and they check the certificate in their PKI. Strangely they can see the whole certification path including the root. I asked them to extract it by using the Copy to File button under Details tab in Windows. They can't export it in .PFX because it was grey out so they sent me a new one in .cer format. When I open it on my local machine, I still got the same thing, the root is still missing in the certification path.

I was lost at this point and I have no clue what might causing this. Do I need to worry about the fact that the root CA is not showing?

From what I can see, either the .PFX or .cer has all the intermediate certificates and the leaf one. Only the root isn't show up in the certificate path. The root CA is in place in the backend setting and the domain `foo-test.bar.com` is installed on the VM

I'd like to hear your opinion on how this happened and the way to fix this. Thank you for taking your precious time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

> The Intermediate certificate is missing from the backend server chain. Please ensure that the certificate chain is complete and correctly ordered on the backend server.

According to [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#the-intermediate-certificate-was-not-found) This error will occur the backend server's certificate chain fails to include the intermediary certificate(s). if self-signed certificate which is NOT a Certificate Authority will also occur same error.

To resolve this issue, when you installed the certificate in .PFX format on the backend server. The root CA certificate, intermediate certificates, and leaf certificates were all bundled together in the PFX file. This full chain needs to be installed when you import the `.PFX file` on the backend server.

[image]

Trusted root certificate is required to whitelist backend instances in application gateway v2 SKU. If there is a custom certificate with intermediate certification authorities, the configuration should be such as:

- The root certificate should be uploaded and used on the backendhttpsetting configuration.
- The remain of the chain (bundle with intermediate certificate(s) + server certificate) must be installed at the backend server for the respective website.

As your mention certificates is in chain make sure Leaf must be topmost in [chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#trusted-root-certificate-mismatch-root-certificate-is-available-on-the-backend-server).

In your root SSL certificate try to export in Base-64 encoded X.509(.CER) root format in Win+R -> certlm.msc -> Local Computer\Personal\Certificates -> export as public -> Base-64 encoded X.509(.CER) [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/certificates-for-backend-authentication) :

[image]

After installing root CA certificate in the appropriate certificate store Application gateway backend status is healthy like below:

[image]

***References***:

[Troubleshoot backend health issues in Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting)

[Trusted root certificate mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#trusted-root-certificate-mismatch-root-certificate-is-available-on-the-backend-server) and [Trusted root certificate mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#leaf-must-be-topmost-in-chain)

[AppGateway V2 Certificate issue -](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/51336/appgateway-v2-certificate-issue) by *GitaraniSharma*